# Read only lines and not the entire thing in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to I make it so in the code below when you register a username and password it it adds a new line to the txt files and when you login it checks every line in the txt files sepretly
and declaring it as correct if any of the lines match the login instead of it checking if the username and password matches the whole thing

```
print "Welcome to UserName and Password Test"
option = raw_input("Would you like to login or register L for Login R for 
register: ")
if option == "R":
    print "Warning Only 1 user can be registered"
    usernamer = raw_input("Desired Username: ")
    passwordr = raw_input("Desired Password: ")
    file = open("Username.txt","w")
    file.write(usernamer + '\n')
    file.close()
    file = open("Password.txt","w")
    file.write(passwordr + '\n')
    file.close
    print "Registered"
else:
    usr = raw_input("Username: ")
    pss = raw_input("Password: ")
    file = open("Username.txt","r")
    if usr == file.read():
        print "Username correct"
        file.close()
    else:
            print "Username incorrect or not registered"
            file.close()
    file = open("Password.txt","r")
    if pss == file.read():
        print "Password correct"
        file.close()
    else:
            print "Password incorrect or not registered"
            file.close()
```

Comment: opening in append mode (use 'a' instead of 'w') will add to the end of a file. Use `file.readlines()` to get a list of lines in a file and then use a loop to check each line for a match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code to validate password and username with a password check logic. This should work.

```
print "Welcome to UserName and Password Test"
option = raw_input("Would you like to login or register L for Login R for register: ")
if option == "R":
    print "Warning Only 1 user can be registered"
    usernamer = raw_input("Desired Username: ")
    passwordr = raw_input("Desired Password: ")
    file = open("Username.txt","a")
    file.write(usernamer + '\n')
    file.close()
    file = open("Password.txt","a")
    file.write(passwordr + '\n')
    file.close
    print "Registered"
else:
    usr = raw_input("Username: ")
    pss = raw_input("Password: ")
    file = open("Username.txt","r")
    count = 0
    userfound = False
    try:
        for user in file.readlines():
            count += 1
            if usr == user.strip():
                userfound = True
        file.close()
        if not userfound:
            raise
        file = open("Password.txt","r")
        passcount = 0
        for passcode in file.readlines():
            passcount += 1
            if count == passcount:
                if pss == passcode.strip():
                    print 'successfully logged in'
                else:
                    print "Password incorrect or not registered"
                break

        file.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print 'User login error !!!'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to find whether a string exists in some line of a file:

```
contain = False # Indicator of whether some line of a file contains the string
with open(FILENAME, 'r') as file: # Use `with` statement to automatically close file object
    for line in file:
        if string in line:
            contain = True
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if the user is in the file contents,

> if usr in file.read():
>         do_somethin

"==" checks if the value are same as it is, "in" keyword checks if the substring is in the huge string. In file.read() will have the whole contents as a string.